# Why do we need to specify "UnityEngine" when using Vector3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

why do we need to specify UnityEngine when using Vector3 in Unity C#?

Especially in this part, I encounter an error when I use only Vector3.
`UnityEngine.Vector3 RandomSpawnPos() { return new UnityEngine.Vector3(Random.Range(-xRange, xRange), ySpawnPos); }`

All the code is like this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;
using System.Numerics;

public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody targetRb;

    private float minSpeed = 12;
    private float maxSpeed = 16;
    private float maxTorque = 2;
    private float xRange = 4;
    private float ySpawnPos = -6;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        targetRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        targetRb.AddForce(RandomForce(), ForceMode.Impulse);
        targetRb.AddTorque(RandomTorque(), RandomTorque(), RandomTorque(), ForceMode.Impulse);
        transform.position = RandomSpawnPos();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }





    UnityEngine.Vector3 RandomForce()
    {
        return UnityEngine.Vector3.up * Random.Range(minSpeed, maxSpeed);
    }

    float RandomTorque()
    {
        return Random.Range(-maxTorque, maxTorque);
    }
    UnityEngine.Vector3 RandomSpawnPos()
    {
        return new UnityEngine.Vector3(Random.Range(-xRange, xRange), ySpawnPos);
    }
```

Explanation for UnityEngine Script :D

Comment: Because of using System.Numerics?

Comment: because you wrote system.numerics as a using (and dont need it) and unity has its own maths  optimized for unity

Comment: @BugFinder Less _"optimized maths"_ - more _not-invented-here-syndrome_ (e.g. .NET's own numerics is hellaoptimized for AVX, whereas Unity is perpetually stuck 4-5 years behind the latest .NET releases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added `using` statements for both the `System.Numerics` and `UnityEngine` namespaces. Each of these namespaces has a definition for `Vector3`.

- [`System.Numerics.Vector3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3?view=net-7.0)
- [`UnityEngine.Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-ctor.html)

So how does the compiler know which of the two implementations you are requesting when you simply write `Vector3()`?

This is like going to a party where more than one person has a given name, lets say `Hakan` for this example. So you go to the party and shout `Hakan!` at the top of your voice and two people turn to look at you, both thinking you were shouting at them.

Therefore to remove ambiguity and inform the compiler which implementation of `Vector3` you desire, you add the namespace prefix.